# How to generate TypeScript _map_ files also on save in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

**Context**

I am using TypeScript in my ASP.NET (MVC) projects. Changing .js / and .ts files then try the new version without executing a build is cool. (just make sure browser cache invalidated). 
I also debug the typescript code in the browser (Chrome currently) and it works great in *TypeScript level* using the generated map file.

So I had set the "Compile on save" in "Project properties"/"TypeScript build".

**Issue:**

Unfortunately the map file is not generated "on save". I had to rebuild the whole project to have the up to date map file. This is extremely painful, and effectively zeros the advantage of Compile on save setting. (Note: In case I was debugging the ASP.NET app serverside C# code too, then for having a rebuild I also must stop the debugger. This iteration is a great candidate to be a productivity killer.)

**So the question remains:**

How to generate TypeScript *map* files also on save in Visual Studio 2015?